# One Drawable-XML-File for Parent and child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want to customize my PopUp-Window. PopUp-Window is an vertical LinearLayout with 3 TextViews.

I want to have a border with Corners around the LinearLayout and smaller bottom borders at the TextViews. Is it possible to do that with one drawable-xml-file? Something like

```
<item Android:id="@id/LinearLayout>
do borders and Corners for LL here
</item>
<item Android:id="@id/TextView1">
do border Corner whatever for TextView1 here
</item>
```

And later adding to every Android:background the same XML-file..
I know it doesn't work this way but maybe someone has an idea.

Comment: Nobody an idea or an easy solution? Without creating 20+ XML-files for every textview or LinearLayout for example?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your description what visual effect you are trying to achieve. A sketch, mock-up, or more detailed explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @alanv The visual effect ist not important... i just have a popup-window which opens when the users clicks the button... and i want to design this popup (which is just a parent vertical layout wih 3 child textviews) with one XML-drawable file... and i want to reference to the textview or linearlayout with the id in the XML-file... do you understand? For example the LinearLayout should have a border on bottom, t, l, and right. But the TextView within it should just have a thiner border on the bottom.. and i want to realize this with one drawable-XML and not with two(one for LL and one for textV